# Can I change a capacitor with one with a higher capacitance?

Tags: capacitance, electrolytic-capacitor, synthesizer, replacement

Hi I have just joined after lurking a lot because I haven't found an answer that was specific enough for me.

I have a Soviet synthesizer (TOM 1501) and it has some odd defects such as clicking noises and sounds disappearing. I want to replace the capacitors in the power supply (only 8) to see if it solves the problem. It consists of three different types of electrolytic capacitors and I can easily find the two (2200uF/25V and 4700uF/16V), but I am having trouble finding one with 70uF/16V.

So I know that you can increase the voltage without it being a problem, but can you increase the capacitance? If yes, by how much?

It would be ideal for it to be axial but as long as it is big enough it can work.

The capacitors that are in the power supply right now are the infamous K50 from the Soviet Union, which are notoriously bad.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Just a note that typical electrolytic cap tolerance is about +/-20%.  So a 70uF cap could have been anywhere from 56 to 84uF when installed.  The value also changes with age, temperature, applied voltage, perhaps even the phase of the moon...

Comment: @rdtsc ±20% is decent for a modern capacitor. The tolerances on a Soviet-era electrolytic were probably much worse. :)

Comment: The ones that are in it have 30% tolerance. but my final question is just: will a 100uF/25V do as a replacement for a 70uF/16V in a power supply on an old keyboard?

Comment: Can i do that? Its all i need to know

Answer (score 1):

Electrolytic capacitors in a power supply are probably being used for smoothing -- they are not precision components. 100 µF is a very common value, and is almost certainly close enough. 68 µF is quite common as well, as are 22 and 47 µF (which sum to 69 µF when used in parallel).

Comment: So i can also change to a lower value? at least if its not too much lower?

And great so i can just use a 100uF instead? assuming it fits in size

Edit: Now i have found some from Nichicon with 100uF/25V. will they do? is it a good brand?

Comment: In theory, yes. Most of the convenient values are higher, though. And yes, Nichicon is a reputable brand.

Comment: Thanks for the answers :) 

what do you mean by 'in theory'?

Comment: maybe i misunderstood you. if the 100uF/25V swap for the old 70uF/16V is alright then i have no more questions

Comment: @SørenHansen  What duskwulff was saying is that in most cases a bigger smoothing capacitor is always better (except price).  If it is used for some other function (not very likely in a PSU) then the answer reverts to _it depends_.

Comment: Thanks :) i just dont want to screw up bad in an old fragile piece of technology. And i have a humanist Education so im not that Well versed in electronics and therefore want to proceed with caution